# flat-surface-shader can't moved by WebGL mode

Tags: javascript, webgl

I use [flat-surface-shader](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/flat-surface-shader/)

Chrome and Firefox moved, but Safari8 and iOS8 Safari can't move flat-surface-shader.

[Warning] WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawArrays: attempt to access out of bounds arrays

[Warning] WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: bufferData: size == 0 (scripts.js, line 1607, x4)

[Warning] WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context. (scripts.js, line 1607)

I want to move flat-surface-shader.

Please help me if you know how to do it.

Comment: Did you enable WebGL in Safari?

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut I enable WebGL in Safari.

Comment: can you post scripts line 1607

Comment: I'm sorry.
https://github.com/wagerfield/flat-surface-shader/blob/master/deploy/fss.js#L907

this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.data, this.gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);